# How to click the href i've encounter TimeoutException and NoSuchElementException error?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code

```
WebElement goToUser = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
                (By.xpath("//a[@class='mat-listed-item ng-star-inserted' and @href='/users']/div[@class='mat-list-item-content']")));
goToUser.click();
```

Here is the xpath

```
/html/body/app-root/app-side-nav/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav/app-side-nav-list/mat-nav-list/div[3]/a
```

and HTML

[image: HTML click here]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In xpath, put B".//app-side-nav-list/mat-nav-list/div[3]/a[@class='mat-listed-item ng-star-inserted']"

Answer (score 0):

That's why long xPath might be hard to work with. To better get to a source of the problem here's how I would split the code (p.s. i also change `xpath` part for a `href` to use `contains`):

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='mat-listed-item ng-star-inserted' and contains(@href, 'users')]"));
    WebElement div = link.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='mat-list-item-content']"));
    WebElement goToUser = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(div));
    goToUser.click();
```

Now if it fails, you will see the exact line and will be able to debug the problem and fix it or specify your question.